# Complex Numbers conceptual question

Tags: complex-numbers

If $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are complex numbers then $\frac{Z_1\overline{Z_2}+\overline{Z_1}Z_2}{2} = Re(Z_1\overline{Z_2})$

what does this mean ? and how is it proved ?

Comment: $\text{Re}\,z$ is the real part of the complex number $z$.

Comment: @Shark yeah I know that , but could you please tell how is this statement true? How can we prove it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\bar{z}$ is just the conjugate of $z$ while $Rez(z)=\Re(z)$ is the real part of the complex number.

So we have
$$\large\frac{z_1\bar{z_2}+\bar{z_1}z_2}{2}=\frac{z_1\bar{z_2}+\overline{({z_1}\bar{z_2})}}{2}=\frac{z+\bar z}{2}=\frac{2\Re(z)}{2}=\Re(z)$$

where $\large z=z_1\bar{z_2}$

Comment: Thank you very much . I understood it !

Comment: @Amanda My pleasure!

Answer (score 3):

Say $Z_1 = a+bi$ and $Z_2 = x+yi$ where $\{a,b,x,y\}\subset\Bbb{R}$. Say $Z_1\overline{Z_2} = R+Ji$ where $\{R,J\}\subset\Bbb R$.

The notation $\overline Z$ means the [complex conjugate](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexConjugate.html) of $Z$. The notation $\operatorname{Re}(Z)$ or $\Re(Z)$ means the [real part](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RealPart.html) of $Z$.

Hence we have

$$\frac{Z_1\overline{Z_2} + \overline{Z_1}Z_2}{2} = \frac{ (a+bi)(x-yi) + (a-bi)(x+yi) }{2}$$

and

$$\operatorname{Re}\left( Z_1\overline{Z_2}\right) = \operatorname{Re}\!\big[ (a+bi)(x-yi) \big] = R$$

Expand and reduce the statements, and see where that gets you. I’ll leave the rest of the proof to you from here. If you’re still having problems later, say so in the comments, and I’ll explain some more.

Comment: Thank you very much . I get it now :)